# DoesNotExist at /settings Profile matching query does not exist. django error

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

this is the profile model

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
      user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      id_user=models.IntegerField()
      bio=models.TextField(blank=True)
      profileimg=models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images',default='defualtdp.png')
      location=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    def _str_(self):
    
      return self.user.username
```

and in the views.py i tried to get the object like this

```
    def settings(request):
       user_profile=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
       return render(request,'setting.html',{'user_profile':user_profile})
```

and passed into settings.html

```
     <img src="{{user_profile.profileimg.url}}">
     <textarea id="about" name="bio"  rows="3"  class="shadow-none bg-gray-100">{{user_profile.bio}}</textarea>
     <input type="text" name="location" value="{{user_profile.location}}" class="shadow-none bg-gray-100">
```

and its showing the error

```
   DoesNotExist at /settings
   Profile matching query does not exist.
```

I am really dont know what to do...

Comment: You don't have profile object for that user. Besides you should change user field to OneToOneField and your '_str_' method to `__str__` with double underscore

Comment: i am not agree with change foreign to o2o. But it is: the profile is not exists.

Comment: Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73425105/7758804) by the OP, I'm voting to close this as not reproducible or caused by a typo.

Answer (score 0):

After I flushed the database and migrations then I reinitialized the migrations now its working.The problem occured when I tried to manually edit the userprofile from admin panel.

Answer (score -1):

```
def settings(request):
   user_profile = None
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
       user_profile=Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
   return render(request,'setting.html',{'user_profile':user_profile})
```